# Float right on clicking the right button and float left clicking the left button using a single function and only javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is what I tried:

--HTML--

```
<div id="box1">
    <button type="button" onClick="float()" value="1" id="left">left</button>   
    <button type="button" onClick="float()" value="2" id="right">right</button>
</div>
```

--CSS--

```
#box1 {
    width:250px;
    height:490px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

--jS--

```
function float() {
var r = document.getElementById("right").value,
l = document.getElementById("left").value
if(r==2){   
    document.getElementById("box1").style.cssFloat="right";
}
if(l==1){
    document.getElementById("box1").style.cssFloat="left";
}
```

}

I tried removing the 2nd if statement and the code worked fine, i.e., float was changed to right. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick for me:

```
function float(move) {
    var name = move,
    side = name.className;
    if(side=="right"){
        document.getElementById("box1").style.cssFloat="right";
    }
    if(side=="left"){
        document.getElementById("box1").style.cssFloat="left";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function float() {
var r = document.getElementById("right").value;
var l = document.getElementById("left").value;
if(r==2){   
    document.getElementById("box1").style.cssFloat="right";
}
if(l==1){
    document.getElementById("box1").style.cssFloat="left";
}
```

Comment: How is that different from what OP had?